# Trying to understand the grammar of “d'autres chambres que seulement celles …”

Tags: grammaire, constructions

There is a particular piece of the following sentence which confuses me. Possibly it is a typo but I am not sure.

> Notez que la salle de bain est partagée avec d'autres chambres que
>   seulement celles situées au même étage.

It's the "que seulement celles" bit. I understand what the sentence is saying but it seems to translate like *Note that the bathroom is shared with other bedrooms which only those situated on the same floor.* That makes no sense. Am I misreading this? Is *que seulement* idiomatic, meaning "though only"?

Comment: @Random, this is not the meaning conveyed by the original sentence. This bathroom is shared not only with rooms on this floor but also with rooms on other floors...

Comment: @GAMPUB Indeed, little confusion, thanks. I deleted my comment into this new one : 
This formulation is also hard to read for the native I am, I have to read it multiple times to be sure of the meaning. On oral, to be understood, the tone may be very important. "**seulement**" is confusing, but knowing the real sense, it is hard to place it elsewhere... On oral, we could say "**Notez que la salle de bain n'est pas seulement partagée avec les chambres de l'étage, mais aussi avec d'autres [chambres].**" for instance. It still sounds not perfect, but at least, the meaining is clear.

Comment: @Random Agreed. And we could pretty safely assume that the writer of the message can be perfectly clear when he needs to. But here he's describing some kind of flaw and, until some misunderstanding really happens, I guess he (commercially) prefers the blurry original to your (perfectly clear and overall better) version in bold. ^^ (Yet again, so many people can't write properly so... who knows)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Seulement* is superfluous here and makes that sentence heavy-handed.

It can be translated by:

> Note that the bathroom is shared with other bedrooms than (just) the ones located on the same floor

i.e.

> The bathroom is shared with  other floors' bedrooms.